# How to include mongodb & redis on a startup script on ubuntu using PM2?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, redis, pm2

I run a node.js express app on an ubuntu digitalocean droplet.
I'm using PM2 to start and monitor my app.
I want to make sure - should the server needs to restart/crash, PM2 includes my Redis & Mongo services upon server restart as they are essential to my app.
I think it's a pretty straight forward generic need, yet wasn't able to find a straight forward answer. I'd appreciate any help.
Cheers
Ajar

Comment: 6 years later ... Did you find a solution for this?